# How to validate salted and hashed password in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, cryptography

I used the below method to salt and hash the passwords

```
public string CreateSalt(int size)
{
    var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var buff = new byte[size];
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}
public string GenerateSHA256Hash(String input, String salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashstring =
        new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
public void Submit1_click(object sender, EventArgs r)
{

    try
    {
        String salt = CreateSalt(10);
        String hashedpassword = GenerateSHA256Hash(password1.Text, salt);
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=root;PASSWORD=abc123;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO authentication(agentlogin ,password ,question ,answer)VALUES ( @login, @pwd, @question, @answer)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", labeluname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", hashedpassword);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", ddlquestion.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", txtanswer.Text);
        connection.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        lblmsg.Text = "Registered succesfully";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.Write("not entered");
        lblmsg.Text = "Registration failed!";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
}
```

So I get the fully encrypted password from the above, but now I can't login using the passwords that was entered in there. How can I unsalt the password when logging in? I figured I can just use the same method used to encrypt to unhash it but the salting doesn't return the same values.
The below is the code on validation page

```
    public string GenerateSHA256Hash(String input)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashstring =
            new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    public void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs r)
    {
        String hashedpassword = GenerateSHA256Hash(txtpassword.Text);
        string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from authentication where agentlogin=@username and password=@word", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", hashedpassword);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["id"] = txtusername.Text;
            Response.Redirect("calendar.aspx");
            Session.RemoveAll();
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Credential doesn't match!";
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }

    }
```

Comment: the salted and encrypted password never been unsalt or decrypt. if you have to match both password then you have to take password from user then you have to salt it first and then encrypt it. and then compare this salted and encrypted input password with salted and encrypted password in database, got it?

Comment: bcoz sha1 or sha256 password once encrypted then never been decrypted

Comment: So do I just do it in reverse when logging in?

Comment: yes that right? if its equal then simply login user otherwise populate message to user that `your username or password is incorrect`

Comment: but lets say my password is "abc123" if I salt I get a encrypted value lets say n, and lets say I salt "abc123" again I will get a different value this time it won't be n.

Comment: @ershoaib I'll try and let you know

Comment: Maxime's answer is good for now but you cant get what you have to do then I'll add an answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create an column in your user table `Username` and `Hash` and `Salt`

**User Register**

1) Take input `username` or `password` from user in your registration form.

2) Create Hash and Salt for input password with below method.

```
public class HashSalt
{
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}

public static HashSalt GenerateSaltedHash(int size, string password)
{
    var saltBytes = new byte[size];
    var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    provider.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
    var salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

    var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 10000);
    var hashPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256));

    HashSalt hashSalt = new HashSalt { Hash = hashPassword, Salt = salt };
    return hashSalt;
}
```

> Rfc2898DeriveBytes class is used to generate the hash using the RFC2898 specification, which uses a method known as PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function #2) and is currently recommend by the IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force) for new applications.

3) Then stored this `Hash` and `Salt` with user record in database.

```
public void Submit1_click(object sender, EventArgs r)
{
    //Your code here

    HashSalt hashSalt = GenerateSaltedHash(64, password1.Text);

    //Your code here

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", hashSalt.Hash);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salt", hashSalt.Salt);

    //You code here
}
```

**User Login**

1) Take input `username` or `password` from user in your login form.

2) In `Login_click` get user by username from database.

3) Pass stored `Hash` and `Salt` to below function.

```
public static bool VerifyPassword(string enteredPassword, string storedHash, string storedSalt)
{
    var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(storedSalt);
    var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(enteredPassword, saltBytes, 10000);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256)) == storedHash;
}
```

4) Then login your user by verifying his/her password.

```
public void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs r)
{
    //You code here

    User user = GetUserByUsername(txtUsername.Text);

    bool isPasswordMatched = VerifyPassword(txtpassword.Text, user.Hash, user.Salt);

    if (isPasswordMatched)
    {
        //Login Successfull
    }
    else
    {
        //Login Failed
    }

    //Your code here
}
```

Reference: [Effective Password Hashing](https://www.ktlsolutions.com/how-tos/effective-password-hashing/)

Comment: @prkash, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: works fine...but when did you assign value to `size`? in my case i set a default value like this `(int size =16)`

Answer (score 3):

You have to store the salt before adding it to the password and hashing it.

So when someome tries to login you concatenate the password with the stored salt and then you can hash it and compare it to the existing hash in base.

So your user table should have at least these 3 columns :
username, hashedpassword, salt

**longer explanation :**
The hashing function is deterministic but not reversable so when the user create his password for the first time :

- you generate a salt
- you concatenate the password and the salt
- you hash the resulting string of the concatenation of password and salt
- you save both the hash and the salt

so you have : hashedpassword = hashingfunction(password+salt)

When you try to login :

- you get the login and password as input
- with the login you can retrieve the hash and the salt in base
- you already have the hashingfunction
- so you can process hashingfunction(password_entered_by_user+salt)
- you compare the result with hashedpassword and log the user if it's the same

Having the salt next to the hashed password doesnt make it less secure : the goal of the salt is to prevent the use of [rainbowtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

If someone breaks into your database he will probably aim for the email+password of your users due to the fact most people reuse the same password and email in a lot of different places.

Now since the hash function is not reversable, the only thing an attacker can do is trying to guess the password and creating a dictionnary with :

```
guessed_password => hash(guessed_password)
```

ex :

```
pet345 => 23FD7890F0F3FA3AE468F37CB900402A1F1977CF926F3452CA519056E16985AB
lola78 => 876B42DC10A0822CC52B894DC7517C784A542B43FB033B4A93635ADA67946B2E
lola79 => A7DCAF5195463FA367CDEA6F23688C1280EC98F4AF2B08BC3469D2496537D48D
lola80 => 8D8E1CF212F5DDC3CA1D510900382DF945625A9AE1584CE0D539B2C4D73717CB
```

if hash(guessed_password) is in your database, he knows the password for this (these) user is guessed_password.

He can generate a dictionnary with billions of guessed_passwords and since a lot of users do not use really strong password, it's very likely that he will be able to find a good number of your users hash in his dictionnary. So if he generates hashes for 'lola80' and 'lola79' and these are the passwords of 2 of your users he know knows it.

Now if you add a random salt to every password entered, for each salt he has to generate a complete dictionary since he has to do :

```
guessed_password + salt = hash(guessed_password + salt)
```

For user A with salt '09ç@p$' he has to generate a full dictionnary where every word ends by '09ç@p$'

Now if he wants to guess the password of user B associated with salt 'Yuè45gh' he has to generate another dictionnary where every word ends by 'Yuè45gh'

Basically it slows down the process of guessing your users passwords by a your_number_of_users factor.

Comment: If I have the hashedpassword column it won't be secure as it would be easy to figure out similar passwords.

Comment: @prkash, only if you both happen on the same random salt. With a big enough salt, that is going to be astronomically rare. If you're really worried, include the primary key of your user add part of the salt so it is different per user.

Comment: @prkash the salt does not help against a targeted bruteforce attack, strong password do, the salf helps against rainbowtable attacks and slows down massively any attack that targets the whole database. I'll edit my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured I can just use the same method used to encrypt to unhash it but the salting doesn't return the same values.

You mean you sent the salted password another time through the salting mechanism and expected an unhashed clear password? This would not make any sense.

So, you salted a password and saved it somewhere. What you are meant to do now is, when a user enters his password, you salt this new password and get a salted password. Then check this new one against the old one; if they match, it was the correct password.

Comment: Yes but salting doesn't return the same values everytime, even if I salt the same password entered again it would not be the same, only hashing returns the same values everytime the same password is used.

Comment: Then you should read @Maxime's answer. I think he understood your problem quite better. As he explains, you store the salt used for each passwords.

Comment: @prkash, it's not a problem if the salt is visible next to the hashed password. An attacker, who uses prehashed passwords will not be able to use them. One would have to guess your password and hash it with your salt for *each* entry in your database, which would just take too long. Pregathered rainbow tables, lookup tables and so on will be useless, if you have a different salt for each password.