# C# Mysql datareader - how to get other column using datareader

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datareader

I'm trying to validate the password from my database that has been hash and salted. I Created an column in my user table username, hash and salt. Now I want to know if I can access the other column value using a datareader.

I tried this method but I got a red line. This is my failed attempt

```
public static bool VerifyPassword(string enteredPassword, string storedHash, string storedSalt)
{
    var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(storedSalt);
    var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(enteredPassword, saltBytes, 10000);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256)) == storedHash;
}

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userhash;
    string usersalt;

    MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login.info WHERE username = @user", mysqlCon);
    MySqlDataReader rd;
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text;
    mysqlCon.Open();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        userhash = rd.GetString("hash");
        usersalt = rd.GetString("salt");

        bool isPasswordMatched = VerifyPassword(textpass.Text, userhash.Hash, usersalt.Salt);
// i got redline error in here. i only follow instruction.. link below
        if (isPasswordMatched)
        {
            //Login Successfull
        }
        else
        {
            //Login Failed
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I only follow this instruction from this thread. [How to validate salted and hashed password in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146528/how-to-validate-salted-and-hashed-password-in-c-sharp?fbclid=IwAR31aDtKv_FHFkIPEhYFADMcpSdL3LTbAqaDOzU-ZlyhbdRvTO9HNEXSdYQ)

Comment: Which line in particular is "red"?

Comment: in similar way as you are gettign hash and salt

Comment: Oh, by the way, you are executing the reader before adding the parameter and then opening your connection.

Comment: It's because you are passing in an object's property. Just pass in the string you received. `VerifyPassword(textpass.Text, userhash, usersalt);`

Comment: Remove the `static` from `public static bool VerifyPassword`. @SimonWilson No, OP declared the method static so the compiler cannot find the method.

Comment: The linked *question*'s code is bad. That's not some kind of tutorial or instructions, that's someone's attempt to talk to the database in a very unsafe manner. If you search for any ADO.NET tutorial you'll see that connections are always created inside `using` blocks to ensure they're closed, how to pass parameters etc. [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html)'s doc site shows how to use it for example, and even how to use it instead of SQL Server with Membership

Comment: @bradbury9 *Remove the static from public static bool VerifyPassword. SimonWilson No, OP declared the method static so the compiler cannot find the method.*  
 **[What???](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7DPFtL)**

Comment: @Selvin "No" to what? Your comment is a little difficult for me to understand

Comment: @SimonWilson it's quote from bradbury9's comment ... and `What???` refers to it

Comment: Ah...hah, just saw it

Comment: @bradbury9 if anything, `static` makes it *easier* to find a method.

Comment: @bradbury9 the OP didn't post the actual compilation error but it won't have anything to do with a public static method declared in the *same* class. Trying to call non-existent `Hash` and `Salt` properties on a `String` though, is a clear compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of writing your code, not really an answer, but...not perfect mind, but at least it will dispose of the objects and also call them in the correct order. Please read upon on IDisposable and Sql Injection.

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
                               // Use a named list of fields please. And cleanse the text.
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login.info WHERE username = @user", mysqlCon))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text; // Let's hope user name is not Jimmy DropTables!!
            mysqlCon.Open();

            using (MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    string userhash = rd.GetString("hash");
                    string usersalt = rd.GetString("salt");

                    bool isPasswordMatched = VerifyPassword(textpass.Text, userhash, usersalt);
                    // Note that we are passing in strings, not props of an unknown object
                    if (isPasswordMatched)
                    {
                        //Login Successfull
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Login Failed
                    }
                }
            }

            mysqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i thinks i works.. i can login using the  original password but in database is hash and salted.. i will test more. But thank you so much..